# Pin IMAP account to Start page?

Tags: pin-to-start

I've added an IMAP account (icloud.com) to my Lumia 920. However, when I press-hold the icon in the application list the Pin to startscreen-option is greyed out. It's not a general fault, because I can pin other apps.

I've not been able to find any info on this, is it just not possible to pin IMAP mailboxes?

Answer (score 2):

After a reboot, I found the IMAP inbox as a tile on the Start Page.